# How to store an array of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have cells in a table, and I want to keep track of any selected cells as they are clicked.  How can I handle this in JavaScript? I don't want to use jQuery-ui to handle the selecting because I am also using dragging, and this is causing conflicts.

Comment: Does each cell have a different id?

Comment: q1: Do you want to track the currently selected cell or the whole chain?
q2: Do you want a simple track, or the entire object? Further explanations required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the cell with jquery with no id:

```
var list;
$('td.cell').click(function(){

    list.push($(this));

});
```

or just id:

```
var list;
$('td.cell').click(function(){

    list.push($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a class called `selected` to each row/cell that has been selected: `$("td").on("click", function(e) { $(e.currentTarget).addClass("selected") })`

After that it's just a simple jQuery selector query to get the list of selected cells: `$(".selected")`